# How to save temptable to Hive metastore (and analyze it in Hive)?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.3

I use Spark 1.3.1.

How to store/save a DataFrame data to a Hive metastore?

In Hive If I run `show tables` the DataFrame does not appear as a table in Hive databases. I have copied `hive-site.xml` to `$SPARK_HOME/conf`, but it didn't help (and the dataframe does not appear in Hive metastore either).

I am following [this document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection), using spark 1.4 version.

```
dataframe.registerTempTable("people")
```

How to analyze the spark table in Hive?

Comment: Are you sure your hive is configured properly? Are you able to query hive tables from beeline or hive shell?

Comment: yes, if i run  sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weather(dates STRING, temp STRING, wind STRING, atmosPressure STRING)") It's creating the table. So It's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insertInto` method to save dataframe in hive.

Example:

```
dataframe.insertInto("table_name", false);
//2nd arg is to specify if table should be overridden
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. I am using spark 1.3.1, so that it's not supporting all. Now using spark 1.5.1 that problem resolved.
I have noticed data-frames fully working after 1.40. Many commands are deprecated.

Comment: run same command in new version 1.4+ than any dataframe work properly get hive data also in spark.